# How To Remove Sidebar From Particular Page In Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "#url"'>
<style>
.main-inner .columns {
padding-left: 0px !important;
padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.main-inner .fauxcolumn-center-outer {
left: 0px !important;
right: 0px !important;
}
.main-inner .fauxcolumn-left-outer, .main-inner .fauxcolumn-right-outer, .main-inner .column-left-outer, .main-inner .column-right-outer {
display: none !important;
}
</style>
</b:if>
```

Above Code Remove All Sidebars In Blogger But I Want To Remove Specific Page Sidebars .

Any Solutions ??

Comment: insert the CSS as a part of the content so it only apply to this page

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way to reduce page load times if your sidebar content takes up a lot of resources would be to remove it completely on those pages rather than "hiding" it.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != "#url"'>
<!--SIDEBAR HTML CODE-->
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isLabelSearch'> 
<style type='text/css'>#sidebar-wrapper {display:none;}</style>
```

***place that code above `</body>`***

I use this and combine with tag condition...  why i placing this code in above `</body>`? cause this last code render... it's simple mind for amateur like me.

that code will remove sidebar wrapper in tag label.

Sorry.. about grammar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.main-inner .columns {
padding-left: 0px !important;
padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.main-inner .fauxcolumn-center-outer {
left: 0px !important;
right: 0px !important;
}
.main-inner .fauxcolumn-left-outer, .main-inner .fauxcolumn-right-outer, .main-inner .column-left-outer, .main-inner .column-right-outer {
display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

give that in your particular page so you can remove your sidebar.