# Remove Left SideBar From Homepage in Blogger

Tags: sidebar, google-blogger-api

I want to hide (or remove) the left side bar from my homepage and have it appear on the other pages. I have not found any solution on the internet that works for me.  I received this link from google help communities, but I cannot make the solution work https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/227967774/remove-sidebar-from-homepage-of-blog?msgid=228361885. I want the homepage to appear as it currently does. I have not added the sidebar to my live site yet, because I am working from a test site. Thank you

I have tried various solutions found on different sites, including this one ([How To Remove Sidebar From Particular Page In Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126257/how-to-remove-sidebar-from-particular-page-in-blogger)) and youtube videos but nothing is working for me. I am not able to locate the exact HTML number in my theme for the left sidebar 1, which would make the solution work, nor can I find the exact wording for the homepage.